# Why is my text not wrapping around my images?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Stupid question maybe, but I cannot seem to get the text to wrap around my images.  In the editor it looks fine, everything is wrapped around it, but when I save it, there is no wrapping.

example: http://www.beatinganger.com/three-reasons-for-angry-children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `float: left;` from `#left_container p`

there's no need to float all the paragraphs you already have the image floating inside the content so it's the only one that needs to float for the `p` or any other element to wrap around it

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may need to add styles to the images, either float left or float right - can't say for sure as the link is broken.

**Edit:** It is because you have width:100% and float:left set on #left_container p, and the images you are adding are wrapped in p tags. Remove width:100% and float:left and you should be back in business.

as clairesuzy says aswell...

Answer (score 0):

Put a `float` on the `<img>` tag. But I suggest to avoid writing css in the tag though, it's not good practice unless you really have to. Do it externally. You can target the image by doing, `p img{ float: left; }` (basic code), depending on the class or id you've giving the tags.